# How to access the data that was assigned to the variable before in Tcl script?

Tags: variables, tcl

I am pretty new to Tcl and have been writing snippets to improve the automation of the process flow in our Work. I want to compare the value of a variable to its previous value so that the code knows its a new flow. The problem is: How to store the old value of a variable? or more precisely, how can we store the value of a variable that is assigned during previous flow?(Is it even possible?)

The following is how our workflow looks like

Start compilation

A) Start phase1 and run flow.tcl script twice

B) Start phase2 and run flow.tcl script twice

...

End compilation

Here in this example, the variable is assigned a new value every time it is run in a different phase. But since I am unable to store the value of the variable to compare, am stuck at trying different options but in vain. This might be totally impossible but as far as I know Tcl can handle almost everything.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Hemanth

Edit: simple solution found. Have the data written to text files and read in back again. Thanks

Comment: Personally, I'd use a SQLite database in place of a text file if there was going to be any kind of volume or multiple runs stored etc... It is included in many distributions and is really simple to use: (e.g. `package require sqlite3; sqlite3 db mydb; db eval {create table procvars(runid, varid, varval);};`) ... Docs on the Tcl API here: https://www.sqlite.org/tclsqlite.html

Answer (score 0):

You can save variables in an array and load the variables back into Tcl.  The command "array get" serializes the data and "array set" puts it back into an array.

### flow.tcl

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

proc load_data {data_file array_name} {
        upvar $array_name data

        if {[file exists $data_file]} {
                set fp [open $data_file r]
                array set data [read $fp]
                close $fp
        }
}

proc save_data {data_file array_name} {
        upvar $array_name data
        set fp [open $data_file w]
        puts $fp [array get data]
        close $fp
}

set now [clock seconds]

# Set defaults. If you need new keys in your data file you can add them here.
set data(count) 0
set data(last_timestamp) $now

# Load existing data over default values. If the key doesn't exist the default will be used.
load_data "flow.dat" data

# Use the saved data to find elapsed time.
set elapsed [expr $now - $data(last_timestamp)]
set count $data(count)

# Save new data.
set data(last_timestamp) $now
set data(count) [incr count]
save_data "flow.dat"  data

puts "It's been $elapsed seconds since last run. You have run this $count times."
```

### output

```
% ./flow.tcl
It's been 0 seconds since last run. You have run this 1 times.
```

### flow.dat

```
% cat flow.dat
count 1 last_timestamp 1427142892
```